# HTML tags not working in emails rails4.1

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

What is the best way to send html formated emails?

I thought 'content = "text/html"' should do the trick but looks like it is not. I am sending email like this:

```
mail(to: <to_email>, from: <from_email>,  subject: <subject>, content_type: 'text/html')
```

Text which I want to send includes linebreaks (lb;) and &nbsp(nb;) like:

```
"Hello <br/> &nbsp; World"
```

Email which I got is just like that:

```
"Hello <br/> &nbsp; World"
```

I would have thought it to come like this:

```
"Hello
  World"
```

Make sense?

**Overall code:**

My controller code:

```
UserMailer.send_message(email_text).deliver`
```

My mailer code

```
def send_message(message)`
  mail(to: "receiver@gmail.com", from: "sender@gmail.com",  subject: "you got a new message" , content_type: 'text/html')`
end`
```

My view code:

```
<%= @message %>
```

When I visit the view page, I see plain linebreaks and nbsp. Do not see the html view.

I think there is one more way(simple_format) to do that but I am not pretty convinced with that.

Comment: How you are sending the text? Please post that code.

Comment: @Pavan, I think I have answered your question in my edited question. :) Please let me know if you want more information.

Comment: Try `<%= @message.html_safe %>` or `<%= raw @message %>`.

Comment: Did my suggestion worked?

Answer (score 0):

Pavan is correct. Additionally, you may need to use the [HTMLEntities](https://github.com/threedaymonk/htmlentities) gem to decode the html entities in the string (eg.  ).